# How to Group List in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to group below list in xamarin forms with Company Name & need to Display in ListView. I have studied that it is possible with ObservableCollection. But I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help this to achive?

**List**

```
public class Phone
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
} 

var phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone {Title="Galaxy S8", Company="Samsung", Price=60000 },
                new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price=50000 },
                new Phone {Title="Huawei P10", Company="Huawei", Price=10000 },
                new Phone {Title="Huawe Mate 8", Company="Huawei", Price=29000 },
                new Phone {Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=38000 },
                new Phone {Title="iPhone 6S", Company="Apple", Price=50000 }
            };
```

**Expected OutPut** (In Xamarin Forms Android,iOS & UWP)

```
Apple
Title : iPhone 6S
Price : 50000

Title : iPhone 7
Price : 38000

Huawei
Title : Huawei P10
Price : 10000

Title : Huawe Mate 8
Price : 29000

Samsung
Title : Galaxy S8
Price : 60000

Title : Galaxy S7 Edge
Price : 50000
```

Comment: Hope this [link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/) will help

Comment: Create JSON and load from it, [check here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37195/json-to-observablecollection-to-be-used-on-listview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a model that contains a grouping with a key that will be used as the header (and value it will be grouped by) and the actual model.

I have created on like this:

```
public class PhoneGroup : ObservableCollection<Phone>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public PhoneGroup(string name)
        : base()
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public PhoneGroup(string name, IEnumerable<Phone> source)
        : base(source)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

This inherits from the `ObservableCollection` and adds a `Name` property that can be used as the key.

Now in your page (or better; vie model) you can add a collection like this:

`public ObservableCollection<PhoneGroup> PhonesList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PhoneGroup>();`

And to add items to it, you will first have to create the group, or check if it exists and add the items to the right group, i.e.:

```
PhonesList.Add(new PhoneGroup("Apple", new[]{ new Phone
            {
                Title = "iPhone 6s",
                Price = 50000
            },
            new Phone
            {
                Title = "iPhone 7",
                Price = 38000
            }}));
```

Now add a `ListView` to your page, I've done it in XAML, and configure the `ItemsSource` to the collection you have defined. To enable grouping, also set the `IsGroupingEnabled` and `GroupDisplayBinding` properties like in the code underneath.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PhonesList}" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The output will look like this:

[image: Grouping list in action]

I've created a sample project for you which can be found [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/GroupingListViewSample) and accompanying [blog post](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/implement-grouping-xamarin-forms-listview/).

Depending on how you load your data you could implement a LINQ query to order your models the right way into the grouped list.

Of course, other approaches are possible. Notably, have a look at the MVVM Helpers library by James Montemagno [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers). The `ObservableRangeCollection` has some handy extensions over the regular `ObservableCollection` and it also holds a `Grouping` model which is a more generic approach to grouping.

As per your comment, to retrieve the data and add it into the groups, you could think along the lines of this:

```
var phonesResult = GetData();

PhonesList.Clear();
foreach (var phone in phonesResult)
{
    if (!PhonesList.Any(company => company.Name == phone.Company))
        PhonesList.Add(new PhoneGroup(phone.Company));

    PhonesList.Single(company => company.Name == phone.Company).Add(phone);
}
```

`GetData` is the call to retrieve your data in JSON, we clear the list to replace everything and then you loop through it and check if the group (company in this case) already exists. If not, we create the group and add the current phone.

This is not the most efficient way, but I think for now the most clear way to explain it to you.

Comment: The above code works when I have add data for different groups. But in my case I will get data as JSON like 

Title="Galaxy S8", Company="Samsung", Price=60000 

I need to group based on the Company that known in runtime. 

I have get data in list. But I don't know how to process with collections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet

```
var list=    phones.GroupBy(item => item.Company)
     .Select(group => new { Company= group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: This code grouped the list. But How to assign this in Listview in Xamarin forms?

Comment: @Ganeshgm7  take a look at this article https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping/groupingSampleListView/groupingSampleListView

Answer (score -3):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


             var phones = new List<Phone> {
                new Phone {Title="Galaxy S8", Company="Samsung", Price=60000 },
                new Phone {Title="Galaxy S7 Edge", Company="Samsung", Price=50000 },
                new Phone {Title="Huawei P10", Company="Huawei", Price=10000 },
                new Phone {Title="Huawe Mate 8", Company="Huawei", Price=29000 },
                new Phone {Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=38000 },
                new Phone {Title="iPhone 6S", Company="Apple", Price=50000 }
            };

             var groups = phones.GroupBy(x => x.Company);

             foreach (var group in groups)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
                 foreach (Phone phone in group)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Title : {0}", phone.Title);
                     Console.WriteLine("Price : {0}", phone.Price);
                     Console.WriteLine();
                 }
             }

             Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class Phone
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Console? This is for a Xamarin.Forms app!