# How to group data list from Preferences in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have lists of Order information stored in Preferences as follows:

```
public class CartUser
{       
    public int IDProduct { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; } 
    public string SupplierID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display a list of `SupplierID` groups, I think of the plan to use Group By

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

```
List<CartUser> cartUsers = new List<CartUser>();
var mycart = Preferences.Get("CartUserAdds", "_mycart");
var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycart).GroupBy(x => x.SupplierID);
cartUsers = (List<CartUser>)getcart;
BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(stdata, cartUsers);
```

However I get the error: `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` right line `cartUsers = (List<CartUser>)getcart;`

**PageOne.xaml**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stdata">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout x:DataType="model:CartUser">
                <Label Text="{Binding SupplierID}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>                            
</StackLayout>
```

**The data I am taken from Preferences:**

```
[{\"IDProduct\":1,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 1\",\"SupplierID\":\"22379356\"},{\"IDProduct\":2,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 2\",\"SupplierID\":\"22379356\"},{\"IDProduct\":3,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 3\",\"SupplierID\":\"12336544\"}]
```

**I want it to display like this**

[image]

I read this article: [How to Group List in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979214/how-to-group-list-in-xamarin-forms). However it sets the display in the ListView. I want it to show up in the StackLayout

Looking forward to a solution from everyone. Thank you!

**Update using CollectionView**

**SupplierIDGrouping.cs**

```
public class SupplierIDGrouping : ObservableCollection<CartUser>
{
    public string SupplierID { get; private set; }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID)
    : base()
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID, IEnumerable<CartUser> source)
        : base(source)
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }

}
```

**PageOne.xaml**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}" IsGrouped="true">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<SupplierIDGrouping> SupplierList { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<SupplierIDGrouping>();

List<CartUser> cartUsers = new List<CartUser>();
var mycart = Preferences.Get("CartUserAdds", "_mycart");
var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycart);
cartUsers = getcart;

foreach (var item in cartUsers)
{
    if (!SupplierList.Any(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID == item.SupplierID))
    {
        SupplierList.Add(new SupplierIDGrouping(item.SupplierID));
    }

    SupplierList.Single(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID== item.SupplierID).Add(item);
}

BindingContext = this;
```

**As a result, it still can't be grouped**

[image]

Comment: StackLayout doesn't have any idea how to handle grouped data.  You would have to build the layout manually

Comment: **Why** do you think `StackLayout` is what you want, for the outer layout? Consider [CollectionView grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping).

Comment: [ListView](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/) and [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping) is what you want , because they both have grouping function ,and you need to adjust the json format to adapt ,please check the sample .

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried to try `CollectionView` and add `IsGrouped="true"`. However the result is still not Grouping. Where did I go wrong? I have updated the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set the  template for group header, try the code below .

```cs
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}"  IsGrouped="true">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding SupplierID}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]