# Show CollectionView Grouping not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218819/how-to-group-data-list-from-preferences-in-xamarin?noredirect=1#comment127604971_72218819) about showing Data Groups from Preferences . As per everyone's input I switched to CollectionView. I have consulted the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping. This is what I have:

```
public class CartUser
{       
    public int IDProduct { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; } 
    public string SupplierID { get; set; }
}
```

**SupplierIDGrouping.cs**

```
public class SupplierIDGrouping : ObservableCollection<CartUser>
{
    public string SupplierID { get; private set; }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID)
    : base()
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID, IEnumerable<CartUser> source)
        : base(source)
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }

}
```

**PageOne.xaml**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}" IsGrouped="true">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<SupplierIDGrouping> SupplierList { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<SupplierIDGrouping>();

List<CartUser> cartUsers = new List<CartUser>();
var mycart = Preferences.Get("CartUserAdds", "_mycart");
var getcart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartUser>>(mycart);
cartUsers = getcart;

foreach (var item in cartUsers)
{
    if (!SupplierList.Any(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID == item.SupplierID))
    {
        SupplierList.Add(new SupplierIDGrouping(item.SupplierID));
    }

    SupplierList.Single(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID== item.SupplierID).Add(item);
}

BindingContext = this;
```

**The data I am taken from Preferences:**

```
[{\"IDProduct\":1,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 1\",\"SupplierID\":\"22379356\"},{\"IDProduct\":2,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 2\",\"SupplierID\":\"22379356\"},{\"IDProduct\":3,\"NameProduct\":\"Name product 3\",\"SupplierID\":\"12336544\"}]
```

**However my results are still not grouped by** `SupplierID`

[image]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you very much!

**Update**

**Data corresponds to 2 groups. Group 1: 2 products, group 2: 1 product**

```
foreach (var item in cartUsers)
{
    if (!SupplierList.Any(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID == item.SupplierID))
    {
        SupplierList.Add(new SupplierIDGrouping(item.SupplierID));
    }

    SupplierList.Single(supplierid => supplierid.SupplierID== item.SupplierID).Add(item);
}

var getresult = SupplierList;
foreach(var i in getresult)
{

}

BindingContext = this;
```

[image]

**Update 2**

```
public class SupplierIDGrouping : ObservableCollection<CartUser>
{
    public string SupplierID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get { return SupplierID; } }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID)
    : base()
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }

    public SupplierIDGrouping(string supplierID, IEnumerable<CartUser> source)
        : base(source)
    {
        SupplierID = supplierID;
    }    
}
```

**PageOne.xaml**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SupplierList}" IsGrouped="true" Header="{Binding Name}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: have you checked the logic that builds `SupplierList`?  If you manually build a small grouped dataset (like they do in the docs example) does it work?

Comment: I have simulated as in the example. it works. However in the docs example they use: `List<>`. I am using `ObservableCollection<>`. I add each value in the list `cartUsers`

Comment: As in my example above. I check the logic by checking if `SupplierID` exists or not. If not, then I create a group `SupplierID` and then proceed further.

Comment: then I suspect your logic is incorrect.  Have you actually examined the data in `SupplierList` after it is created?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verify it is behaving as expected?

Comment: Yes, I checked, in the foreach loop I see it 2 times creating `SupplierIDGrouping`. The data in `SupplierList` and `BindingContext` I get is still the same 3 lines --> 3 products respectively. However, it cannot be grouped.

Comment: I tried checking the `SupplierList` data in the loop. I noticed it seems to have created 2 Groups as expected. However, the display in the UI is not like that. What did I mistake? I have updated the above.

Comment: Unless you create a custom group header in xaml, SupplierIDGrouping needs a `Name` property to show as header. Add `public string Name => SupplierID;` Be sure to use `=>`. OR the equivalent `public string Name { get { return SupplierID; } }`

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work. Can you be more clear by answering? I have updated the above. I respect it very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to provide a `GroupHeaderTemplate` to make it work.  Not sure why - according to the docs it should not be necessary

```
    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding SupplierID}"
               BackgroundColor="LightGray"
               FontSize="Large"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: This really works. I appreciate it very much. Thanks